# How can I add custom elements to the detail section of a SoapFault using PHP's SOAP library

Tags: php, soap, soapfault

I am building a service against [Sonos' Music API (SMAPI)](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/). Sometimes I have to send back a response in the following format:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>Client.NOT_LINKED_RETRY</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Link Code not found retry...</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ExceptionInfo>NOT_LINKED_RETRY</ExceptionInfo>
            <SonosError>5</SonosError>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am building my service using the [PHP SOAP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) and for the above response I tried throwing a [`SoapFault`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapfault.php) like this:

```
throw new SoapFault('Client.NOT_LINKED_RETRY', 'Link Code not found retry...');
```

But when I try this the response that is sent back looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>Client.NOT_LINKED_RETRY</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Link Code not found retry...</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <SonosError/>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Notice that there is no `ExceptionInfo` and that `SonosError` is empty. Is it possible to set `ExceptionInfo` and `SonosError` using `SoapFault`? I tried all kinds of things, but couldn't get it working, so as a work around I am doing this now:

```
http_response_code(500);
header("Content-type: text/xml");

$ret = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";
$ret .= '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
$ret .= '<SOAP-ENV:Body>';
$ret .= '<SOAP-ENV:Fault>';
$ret .= '<faultcode>Client.NOT_LINKED_RETRY</faultcode>';
$ret .= '<faultstring>Link Code not found retry...</faultstring>';
$ret .= '<detail>';
$ret .= '<ExceptionInfo>NOT_LINKED_RETRY</ExceptionInfo>';
$ret .= '<SonosError>5</SonosError>';
$ret .= '</detail>';
$ret .= '</SOAP-ENV:Fault>';
$ret .= '</SOAP-ENV:Body>';
$ret .= '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'."\n";

echo $ret; exit;
```

Not sure if it's relevant but the WSDL can be found [here](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/sites/default/files/Sonos.wsdl).

Update: when I try the suggestion below like this:

```
$detail = new StdClass();
$detail->SonosError = 5;
$detail->ExceptionInfo = 'NOT_LINKED_RETRY';

throw new SoapFault(
  'Client.NOT_LINKED_RETRY',
  'Link Code not found retry...',
  NULL,
  $detail
);
```

I get:

```
<detail>
  <customFault>
    <SonosError>5</SonosError>
    <ExceptionInfo>NOT_LINKED_RETRY</ExceptionInfo>
  </customFault>
</detail>
```

This is almost what I need, except for `<customFault>` tag. Is there a way to get rid of it and have `SonosError` and `ExceptionInfo` in `<detail>` directly?

Comment: Can you change the wsdl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you don't see the `ExceptionInfo` tag is because it is not defined in the wsdl. On the other hand `SonosError` is defined. 
First thing first, in order to fill the `SonosError` you have to pass the arguments.

From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapfault.php) you can see that the constructor has more parameters

```
SoapFault('code', 'string', 'actor', 'detail', 'name', 'header');
```

In order to pass the `SonosError` call it like this

```
$detail = new StdClass(); 
$detail->SonosError = 5;
throw new SoapFault('Client.NOT_LINKED_RETRY', 'Link Code not found retry...', null, $details);
```

As for the `ExceptionInfo`, the wsdl must be changed. As it is now, the `details` tag is represented by this sections

```
<wsdl:message name="customFault">
    <wsdl:part name="customFault" element="tns:SonosError"/>
</wsdl:message> 

<xs:element name="SonosError" type="xs:int"/>
```

If you change the above sections with these, you will have what you need.

```
<wsdl:message name="customFault">
   <wsdl:part name="customFault" type="tns:customFaultType" />
</wsdl:message>

<xs:complexType name="customFaultType">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="SonosError" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="ExceptionInfo" type="xs:string"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And of course you add the parameter and the array becomes like this

```
$detail = new StdClass(); 
$detail->SonosError = 5;
$detail->ExceptionInfo = 'NOT_LINKED_RETRY';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had tried all those other arguments, but couldn't get it working. I thought of passing `$details` as an array, but in the documentation it says `string $detail`, so I figured an array won't be accepted. I will try you suggestion.

Comment: When I try with an object instead of an array, I almost get what I need. The only problem is that `SonosError` and `ExceptionInfo` are inside an `<customFault>`. Is there a way to get them inside `<detail>` directly? In other words: how can I get rid of `<customFault>`?

Comment: In the end I didn't need `ExceptionInfo`, so I just did: `$detail = new StdClass(); $detail->SonosError = 5; throw new SoapFault('Client.NOT_LINKED_RETRY', 'Not linked yet; please try again.', NULL, $detail);` Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: You may want to change your answer to details as an object rather than an array, because for me array didn't give the desired result, whereas an object did.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, although I didn't provide a full solution. I will change the answer as per your suggestion. Have fun.